# Валидация модели реквеста

Tags: asp.net-core, валидация, swagger

Со сваггера отсылается модель в виде:

```
{
    Bool1 : true,
    Bool2 : false,
    String1 : "row1",
    String2 : row2
}
```

Два була и два стринга. Проблема в том, что провалидировать на null довольно просто через FluentValidator, но если передать в булевых полях число, к примеру

```
{
Bool1 : 123
}
```

То придет true или false в зависимости от числа. Отсюда вопрос, как можно предотвратить отправку чисел, или сделать валидацию уже после получения модели со сваггера(что лично мне кажется нереальным, поскольку конвертация происходит дополучения данных и дальше мы будем валидировать полноценный бул с неправильным значением и проверка на int не выдаст exception)? Рассматривал Json Schema , но пока не понял, поможет она или нет.
Работаю с ASP Core.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage="The field Is Active must be checked.")]
```